# Converting imported dates from SPSS portable file via memisc

Tags: r, spss

I've been teaching myself to use R for around 6 months and find that when I can't find a solution online it's either an obscure problem or so obvious nobody would ever ask it.

I think this is the latter of these.

Essentially I've imported an SPSS file via R's memisc package using:

```
misc.MP.data <- as.data.frame(
as.data.set(
spss.portable.file("SPSS data.por")))
```

Everything works great, except dates appear to have been imported in a numeric format I'm not familiar with (and I've had no luck finding something similar online).

For instance:

- 10/11/1946 imports as: 11,489,040,000
- 23/11/1946 imports as: -1,394,738,688
- 11/12/1946 imports as: -1,393,183,488
- 18/12/1946 imports as: -1,392,578,688

Although I realize that R and SPSS have different reference points for their dates, adjusting them based on this didn't get me anywhere (such as via [this function](http://scs.math.yorku.ca/index.php/R:_Importing_dates_from_SPSS)).

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to everybody for your responses, I managed to solve the problem, although am unsure precisely why it occurred.

I usually use the csv format when saving and importing data, however, in this instance I was teaching a local organization trying to move from SPSS to R how to easily import data to R.

I don’t have SPSS so I was using PSPP to read and understand the SPSS file to check whether the import worked successfully. However, I found when trying to import the .sav file using the ‘foreign’ command etc in R that the variable labels wouldn’t import properly.

After a bit of trial and error I found that saving as a portable format file via PSPP and importing via the read.portable command from memisc package seemed to work best except dates were imported as described above (including the weird 10/11/1946 one).

Although I realize SPSS and R use a different base for dates, initially I noticed the imported SPSS dates didn’t seem to share the expected linear relationship with the correct dates (see plot below):
 [Imported date vs. correct date scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvBxw.png)

Although I didn't figure out why this had occured, for those who might come across a similar issue the solution I used was to change the variable type in PSPP from ‘date’ to ‘string’ and convert it to an R date using :

```
as.Date(MP.data$dob, format = "%d-%b-%Y")
```

Wish I'd thought of doing it the easy way earlier!

Comment: Did 10/11/1946 really import as 11,489,040,000?  It seems peculiar that it would import as 12,000,000,000 seconds after the other dates when it happened before it.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, in fact it did which is why I'd assumed it wasn't simply a matter of changing the base.

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim to understand why, but the origin of your date appears to be `1991-02-02 19:24:48 EST`. How did I decide this?

I converted your known dates to `POSIXct` objects

```
dt <- c("23/11/1946", "11/12/1946", "18/12/1946")
dt <- as.POSIXct(dt, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Your numeric values were negative.  I put them in a vector, but also knew that to find the origin, I'd need to add the multiplicative inverse.

```
num <- c(-1394738688, -1393183488, -1392578688)
dt + num * -1
```

Again, I don't have any idea why this is the case.  But at the very least, you can identify an origin on which to base your conversions.  You can even bundle this into a function to assist you in the future:

```
find_origin <- function(known_date, known_numeric, ...)
{
  #* ... additional arguments to as.POSIXct
  as.POSIXct(known_date, ...) + known_numeric * -1
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this Benjamin! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the portable file format is deprecated and does not support all the features of Statistics.  It does not support Unicode mode or long variable names.  If you can control how the data are saved, use one of the many other formats provided.

Dates in SPSS are stored as floating point numbers whose value is the number of seconds since Oct 14, 1582.

I have no idea how spss.portable.file handles date values, but the doc does not mention using the format information in the file, which would be the only way to know that it is a date value.

I tried, exporting a known sav file with a date variable with value in the range you posted as portable and reading with code such as above, and the raw numbers do not match what you reported, even for positive values, so I would be cautious about the data.

But then I tried a asPOSIXct conversion using the known origin like this

```
as.POSIXct(dta$bdate, origin = "1582-10-15")
```

and the numbers matched.  Note that the origin date is Oct 15, not 14.  If the dates might have a time component, you might need to specify the `tz` argument to `asPOSIXct`.